# Looking up an EJB dynamically

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I'm developing an application on Glassfish 3. I have an EJB that looks like this:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
  public void doSomething() {}
}
```

My client code (running inside the same application) looks like this:

```
MyBean mb = (MyBean) InitialContext.doLookup(MyBean.class.getName());
```

According to a few sources, this should be a valid lookup method, but it throws a NameNotFoundException. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what sources? I would personally use portable JNDI names specified in EJB 3.1. See:

- [Portable Global JNDI names](http://blogs.oracle.com/MaheshKannan/entry/portable_global_jndi_names) by Mahesh Kannan
- [What is the syntax for portable global JNDI names in EJB 3.1?](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#What_is_the_syntax_for_portable_global_) in GlassFish's EJB FAQ
- [Portable Global JNDI Names](http://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/portable_global_jndi_names) by Ken Saks
- [Application-specified Portable JNDI Names](http://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/application_specified_portable_jndi_names) by Ken Saks

Depending on the packaging, I would use a module-scoped or an application-scoped JNDI name.

BTW, GlassFish logs the portable JNDI names at deployment time.

Comment: My sources: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/35010 and http://www.roseindia.net/ejb/ejb-lookup.shtml. Seems that both of them are completely full of shit.

Comment: @Mike Prior to EJB 3.1, JNDI names were not standardized so there is no general rule, JNDI names are app server dependent. PS: I tend to ignore roseindia and devx "tech tips", I don't consider them as high quality resources.