# JavaEE 7: EJB jndi-name without interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jndi

I use GF4 server and in its log I have:

> Portable JNDI names for EJB com.test.cms.svr.web.Service2:
>   [java:global/com.test.cms.svr.web_1.0.0/com.test.cms.svr.web.Service2,
>   java:global/com.test.cms.svr.web_1.0.0/com.test.cms.svr.web.Service2!com.test.fw.svr.web.bundle.ComponentService]]]

My questions:

1. Why are there two jndi names - with interface and without interface?
2. Why can I get bean only using jndi-name with interface even when EJB is only local?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Why are there two jndi names - with interface and without interface?**

This is an EJB 3.1 feature called portable JNDI names. Here is nice explanation from [this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/MaheshKannan/entry/portable_global_jndi_names):

> Client applications need to use global JNDI name to lookup an EJB. All
>   along the ejb specifications had been silent about portability of such
>   global jndi names. This allowed each vendor to assign a global jndi
>   names to EJBs in a vendor specific way. This meant that the client
>   code that performed a lookup using global JNDI names were inherently
>   non portable across appserver vendor implementations.
>
> EJB 3.1 solves the above problem by mandating that every container
>   must assign (at least one) well defined global JNDI names to EJBs. The
>   general syntax of a (portable) global JNDI name of an EJB is of the
>   form:
>
> **`java:global/[<application-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-bean-interface-name>`**
>
> In addition to the above name, if the EJB exposes just a single client
>   view (that is it implements just one interface or the no interface
>   view), the container is also mandated to map the bean to
>
> **`java:global/[<application-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>`**
>
> Where
>
> 1. `<application-name>` defaults to the bundle name (.ear file name) without the bundle extension. This can be overridden in
>      application.xml. Also,  is applicable only if the
>      bean is packaged inside a .ear file.
> 2. `<module-name>` defaults to bundle name (.war or .jar) without the bundle extension. Again, this can be overridden in ejb-jar.xml.
> 3. `<bean-name>` defaults to the unqualified class name of the bean. However, if `@Stateful` or `@Stateless` or `@Singleton` uses the name
>      attribute, then the value specified there will be used as the bean
>      name.

There is some additional GlassFish-specific information in [the GlassFish EJB FAQ](https://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#What_is_the_syntax_for_portable_global_).

> **Why can I get bean only using jndi-name with interface even when EJB is only local?**

I guess you mean a lookup from another EJB or module in the same web application inside the same JVM. Otherwise this shouldn't be possible without a `@Remote` interface. Here are two statements from the GlassFish EJB FAQ:

> **I have an EJB component with a Local interface. Can I access it from an Application Client or a stand-alone java client ?**
>
> If the EJB component is running within the server, no.  The EJB Local
>   view is an optimized invocation path that uses call-by-reference
>   semantics.   It is only available to web components and EJB components
>   that are part of the same application as the target EJB component.
>   To access EJB components that are running in the server from an
>   Application Client or stand-alone java client,  you'll need to use
>   either a Remote 3.x Business interface, a 2.x Home interface, or web
>   services.
>
> One alternative, if using GlassFish v3, is to use the EJB 3.1
>   Embeddable API.  This allows a Java SE program to directly execute EJB
>   components within the same JVM, without using a server process.
>
> **I have an EJB component with a Local interface.  Can I access it from a web component in a different application?**
>
> No.  The EJB specification only requires access to an EJB component's
>   local EJB interface from within the same application in the same JVM. 
>   One option is to package the ejb-jar in the same .ear as the .war.   A
>   second option, if using GlassFish v3, is to package the EJB component
>   directly within the .war.

The GlassFish EJB FAQ also contains alot more detailed information about this topic.

**See also:**

- [Looking up an EJB dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402317/looking-up-an-ejb-dynamically)
- [Consuming local EJB, in the same Container but different ears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203251/consuming-local-ejb-in-the-same-container-but-different-ears)

Comment: Thank you for your time. 1)"In addition to the above name, if the EJB exposes just a single client view (that is it implements just one interface or the no interface view), the container is also mandated to map the bean" - however it doesn't work 2)the question is not about local and remote but about using interface name in jndi name while looking up.

Comment: It is not really clear what you you are trying to say. Maybe you can add an example to your question.